# CallWndProc hook not receiving all messages

Tags: c#, hook, setwindowshookex

I am making a little tool like Displayfusion and I need some Hooks to receive messages when Windows move/activate/etc , however I'm stuck..

I am using this project for the CallWndProc hook: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx

For pretty much all windows it works great(x86 and x64), however on some windows it seems to can't inject the hook DLL. Currently I am having problems with adobe reader X. No messages are being received from that window. I think it has something to do with the sandbox? Can somebody give me a push in the right direction?

The initialization code for the hook:

```
bool InitializeCallWndProcHook(int threadID, HWND destination)
{
  if (g_appInstance == NULL)
    return false;

  if (GetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HWND_CALLWNDPROC") != NULL)
    SendNotifyMessage((HWND)GetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HWND_CALLWNDPROC"), RegisterWindowMessage("WILSON_HOOK_CALLWNDPROC_REPLACED"), 0, 0);

  SetProp(GetDesktopWindow(), "WILSON_HOOK_HWND_CALLWNDPROC", destination);
  hookCallWndProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)CallWndProcHookCallback, g_appInstance, threadID);

  return hookCallWndProc != NULL;
}
```

Comment: Adobe is the kind of company that worries a great deal about security.  Flash is obvious, but Reader is no exception, given that it can display documents that prevent copy/pasting.  You'll need to contact them for support.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try if Spy++ can catch the messages. If it can, then obviously it's not a problem with security measures. It Spy++ can't however, then it's pretty much impossible.

See if this works: Use both WH_CALLWNDPROC and WH_GETMESSAGE hooks, since apparently, the former only catches sent message, and the latter only catches posted messages.

Comment: I just tried it with Spy++, and Spy++ is able to receive messages from adobe reader X. I will try both both WH_CALLWNDPROC and WH_GETMESSAGE hooks as soon as I have some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar Problem in my application. Visit the following link:

[Strange behaviour of windows hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115244/strange-behaviour-of-windows-hooks)

My guess ist that an application interrupts the filter function chain by not calling the `CallNextHookEx` method. Note that is this only possible when you are using `WH_CBT` hooks.

Comment: Hmm I will try later today if Outlook works with my CBT hook. An alternative could also be this Shell hook: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644989(v=vs.85).aspx. This hook is also used by the Windows Taskbar.